# Add document to envelope based on tempalte

Tags: docusignapi

I'm not very familiar with DocuSign or its API and after playing around in Postman I'm still not sure if I'm able to:

1. Create an Envelope based on a Template
2. Attach a pdf doc to said Envelope
3. Send for signing.

In case I got it all wrong, I'm trying to do the following:
Get the pdf doc from a third party and send it for signing via DocuSign. The document will be the same format every time(same signature placement, names, etc) except for data in it and it will be sent to the same people for signatures.

Is it possible to do so? Am I looking at right stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely possible. We in fact have existing Postman requests that do just that:

https://www.postman.com/docusign/workspace/docusign-s-public-workspace/request/14257714-ef2d10ba-b540-4644-93a1-b0344c0dd82c

Examples number 15 to 18 are the ones you want to look at.

To get started with our Postman collection, you can watch our youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mV73U2tg9c0&t=6s

Comment: Not sure if I understand completely from those examples but I want to: create an envelope from an existing template and adding to that envelop a pdf document and send it. The examples suggest that I can create a template each time I want to attach a doc. Can't a template already exist with everything and I just use that and attach a new doc(but with the same format) each time?

Comment: If you're trying to add a document to an existing template, you can create your envelope using CompositeTemplates: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates

In your case, you'll set you existing template as a serverTemplate and you'll replace the document using the "document" field.